# Run script containg document.write with getElementsByTagName

Tags: javascript, responsive-design, append

I have a script that I want to put on my page which uses document.writeln.

eg

```
    document.writeln('myjs');
```

When I implement the code like this

```
    <script src="http://www.example.com/js/script_v1.js"></script>
```

It works no problems.

However I am doing a reposnsive template so depending on the screen width I want to run different versions of the file.

If I try and implement it like the below It appears in the head but doesn't seem to run the code?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        if(aaa)  {
            myvar=2;
        }
        else {
            myvar=1;
        }

    loader = document.createElement('script');
    loader.src = "http://www.example.com/js/script_v" + myvar + ".js";
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(loader);
    </script>
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script will be loaded async, so you can not use write() or writeln() because the document is closed. Load it sync, so:

```
document.write("<script src='http://www.example.com/js/script_v" + myvar + ".js'></script>");
```

However it is not a good practice, try to avoid *writing* methods.

Answer (score 0):

Is aaa defined? This should work.

Look in your console and see if there are any errors.

http://codepen.io/granttimmerman/pen/vErnG

If you pull up the console, you will see

```
GET http://www.example.com/js/script_v2.js 404 (Not Found)
```

In addition, you might want to create the script element this way (depending on your doctype).

```
  var fileref = document.createElement('script')
  fileref.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript')
  fileref.setAttribute('src', filename)
```

Comment: yes the script loads however it doesn't execute the document.write